# Excel Pivot Table, calculate count of column fields as percentage of total

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Excel Pivot Table, is there any way to create a column that calculates the number of times a value shows up in a specific column relative to the total number of fields in that column as a percentage of the total?

Comment: Might want to give a screenshot or sample of your data & expected results. You'll have to make expected results manually until you get a response if Excel can do this. Hopefully you aren't trying to get someone to do your homework?

Comment: Is this relevant for you only for pivot tables? Or do you want to know how to do this also in ordinary tables?